# Unusual values in watch window when passing struct as argument in x64

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am pretty new to C++ and have come across something I can't explain or do not understand.

I have a simple program that defines a struct and then creates a variable of that type and passes it as an argument to a function.

```
struct Vector3
{
    float X, Y Z;
};

static void test(Vector3 x)
{
}

int main()
{
    Vector3 x = { 100.0f, 100.0f, 0.0f };
    test(x);
    return 0;
}
```

When running in a x86 configuration, inspecting the x argument in the test function, looks absolutely like I expect. X = 100.0f, Y = 100.0f and Z = 0.0f.

However if I change this to x64 now when I inspect the argument in the debugger I get values X = 4.23084696e-37, Y = 2.648e-43#DEN, Z = -107374176.

If I change test to take a pointer instead then the values look sensible again.

Why are they different only when built and running in x64?

The above demonstrates the issue I am having. In my actual code I am passing the position vector to a draw sprite function which is calculating a transform matrix which is used to draw a sprite in open gl. However depending on how I pass the arguments seems to cause a different transformation to be calculated. Could the above be causing this issue or would it be something else?

Comment: Did you optimize your executable?

Comment: It is normal when you try to debug the optimized Release build of your app.  If you use VS2015 then be sure to apply the updates, it was originally released with lots of debugger bugs.

Comment: @HansPassant It does seem to be a bug in VS. I upgraded to update 3 and the watch window is now behaving correctly. If you answer I'll mark you as the accepted answer :)

Comment: Congratulations.  You have everything you need to complete this Q+A yourself, just write it up and accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It seems this was caused by a bug in Visual Studio 2015. Upgrading to update 3 has fixed the issue.